# how to fill missing values with average of each column

Tags: python, pandas

[image: my table]

```
   y12N=y12N.fillna(y12N.mean())
```

I have tried this among other things, this isn't filling any  data to my columns as the table stays the way it is. NaN values are np.NaN values.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. This means include all data [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52079391/edit), i.e. no images/links, just text.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it this way:

```
columnsWithNa = ['column1', 'column2']
for column in columnsWithNa :
    df[column].fillna(df[column].mean()[0], inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# To read data from csv file
Dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

# To get values in variable 'X'
X = Dataset.iloc[:, :].values

# To calculate mean use imputer class

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)


 imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, :])
 X[:, :] = imputer.transform(X[:, :])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to fill `NaN` with each column's respective `mean()`:

```
y12N = y12N.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```